# Looking for mathematics teaching article

Tags: education

Some time in the last month, I read a great article somewhere on the web that discussed the sorry state of secondary school math education in the U.S. One of the examples in that article was a discussion of how geometry is designed to wring the last bit of joy out of mathematics, and included the "formal" proof that a triangle inscribed in a circle with one side on the diameter is a right triangle together with a lovely almost-proof that one of the writer's seventh-graders came up with.

I unaccountably failed to bookmark the article, and would love to find it again. Does this ring any bells with anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you thinking of [*A Mathematician's Lament*](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf)?

Comment: Excellent article, by the way.

Comment: I know. I was really kicking myself for not bookmarking it. I thought it was maybe on the maa website, but their search engine is just awful. I figured someone here would know what it was.

Comment: Now that the question is answered, you may find interesting to read Edward Frenkel's Op-Ed on the LA Times, [*How our 1,000-year-old math curriculum cheats America's kids*](http://www.latimes.com/opinion/commentary/la-oe-adv-frenkel-why-study-math-20140302,0,5177338.story#ixzz2xssleFSB).